# Limit with a definite integral

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm trying to understand how this problem works:

$$\lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{\int_0^{x} (arctg(t))^2 ~ dt}{\sqrt{x^2+1}} = [\frac{\infty}{\infty}] = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{ (arctg(t))^2\Bigg|_{0}^{x}}{\frac{2x}{2\sqrt{x^2+1}}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{ (arctg(t))^2\Bigg|_{0}^{x}}{\frac{x}{x\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}} = \lim_{x \rightarrow +\infty} \frac{ (arctg(t))^2\Bigg|_{0}^{x}}{\frac{1}{\sqrt{1+\frac{1}{x^2}}}} = \frac{\pi^2}{4} $$

Specifcally the parts about finding the limit of the integral and then computing its derivative, everything else makes sense to me. I know it's a simple problem, but I don't fully understand how it works. Could someone help out?

Comment: l’hospital rule...

Comment: That part I understand, my question is about finding the limit and derivative of the definite integral in the limit.

Comment: @perryP Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Note that you can get proper formatting for operators like $\operatorname{arctg}$ by using `\operatorname{arctg}`.